# Usability Heuristic - User Control & Freedom

Tags: user-behavior, controls, heuristics

I'm running an UX project and need help from you guys. Usability Heuristic states that we should include "Redo" "Undo" button for users. I wonder if "Reset" button (for example: reseting all the settings of the app to default value after editting) has the same impact like these two above?

Question is: When would we include "Reset" button in our app? When not? Should we include both "Redo" & "Reset" option for users?

Thank you very much :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When use?**

- Long forms
- Settings
- When the system stops responding

**Should we include both?**

Depends on the context

---

Often it is also needed to return the settings to the default mode (this is also a reset)

If we have a lot of fields(+10) in the form, and it turns out that they are not current then the reset button will make things easier

---

It can be helpful, but you should protect that the user performed the operation by accident. if someone accidentally presses this button, frustration and damage can be significant.

In this case, material design uses an element in the interface that appears for 3 seconds and is able to undo a destructive action.

[image]